# XPath Select Element by Values of a number of childs

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I have a XmlDocument and a list of objects who encapsulates the name and the value of a child of an XmlElement. Basically, the list contains the composite key for an XmlElement.
I cannot find the right XPath to get the XmlElement by the "composite key" or the expression in LINQ.

The Xml Document is something like this:

```
<Document>
  <ITEM>
    <HEADER>
      <No>1</No>
      <Description>Item 1</Description>
    </HEADER>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <HEADER>
      <No>2</No>
      <Description>Item 2</Description>
    </HEADER>
  </ITEM>
</Document>
```

An if the list of keys something like this( a list in c#):

```
Keys= {
{Tag: "No", Value: "1"},
{Tag: "Description", Value: "Item 1"}
}
```

I want to get the first "HEADER" element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<int, string> dict = doc.Descendants("HEADER")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Element("No"), y => (string)y.Element("Description"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```